# Will AWS Network Load Balancer Multiplex HTTP Requests from Multiple Clients to the Same TCP Connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, web, load-balancing

If so, can this behavior be disabled? (so every client connection will be represented with a matching backend connection).

In order to use AWS Network Load Balancer in front of a web server (HTTP 1.1), does the web server need to support serving multiple end-users from the same TCP connection?

Answer (score 6):

Network Load Balancer does not multiplex connections together.

Unlike the other flavors of ELB, Network Load Balancer is essentially a dynamic network address translator, changing the destination address in packets on the way in (balancer IP/port becomes instance IP/port) and changing the source address on the way out (instance IP/port becomes balancer IP/port).

Each connection is independent, 1:1.

The instance will see the actual client source address, except when the balancer is used in a VPC PrivateLink configuration, in which case the client address and source port are also rewritten in similar fashion, so that IP address space conflicts between VPCs are not an issue.

Comment: Multiplexing being essence of load balancing, why would anyone want to use NLB then?

Comment: @AniketChopade that assertion is overly broad.  Multiplexing is arguably a fundamental benefit of a layer 7 load balancer like ALB or Classic ELB in HTTP mode, but for a balancer operating at lower layers, unaware of higher layers, "multiplexing" isn't a valid concept.  NLB is *designed* for 1:1 mapping of TCP connections.  It has no awareness of the protocol running on the connection.  It could be anything -- SSH, SMTP, RDP just to pick a few.  This is true even when the balancer provides TLS offloading -- it has no concept of the meaning of the cleartext payload inside the TLS.

Comment: Okay, thanks. point understood about being at lower layer. That also mean, if client can't make +1 connection with my TCP server(s) there is no point in keeping multiple targets(dynamic port mapping) behind NLB .

Comment: @AniketChopade any given connection only goes to 1 target of *n* in the appropriate target group.  It's unclear what you are referring to as "dynamic port mapping."

Comment: AWS ECS/docker containers can run on multiple ports on 1 ec2. NLB supports dynamic port mapping which means it can load balance between multiple ports/containers ( where each port is 1 target). This feature is useless if client can only have 1 connection at a time.